# Perturbation of the spectrum of a matrix by adding small decaying coefficients.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**BACKGROUND & MOTIVATION:** We consider in a complex infinite-dimensional Hilbert space a bounded operator $T$. We pick a Hilbert basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ and project $T$ onto it: for all $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$, we let
\begin{align*}
T_N&:=(\langle e_m,Te_n\rangle)_{|m|,|n|\leq N}
\end{align*}
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product of the Hilbert space. The main motivation is to determine whether $0$ is in the spectrum of $T$ or not. **We assume** that $T$ is of the form $\mathrm{1}+K$ where $K$ is trace-class, so that $T$ is Fredholm of index $0$: in particular, its spectrum consists in eigenvalues and $0$ is an eigenvalue if and only if the Fredholm determinant $\det(\mathrm{1}+K)$ cancels. Since $T_N\to T$ as $N\to+\infty$ in the operator norm topology, we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to+\infty}\det((\langle e_m,Te_n\rangle)_{|m|,|n|\leq N})&=\det(T).
\end{align*}
Since $K$ is compact, **we do know that the non-zero eigenvalues of $K_N:=(\langle e_m,Ke_n\rangle)_{|m|,|n|\leq N}$ converge to non-zero eigenvalues of $K$**.

Now the goal is to give an estimate on the rate of convergence of the eigenvalues of $K_N$ with, say, modulus greater than $1/4$, to their limits in the spectrum of $K$. In the literature, such an estimate relies on bounding the resolvent $(K-\lambda)^{-1}$ for $\lambda$ on a small contour enclosing an eigenvalue of $K$, which is not feasible in practice.

---

Fix $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$ and $N'>N$. To simplify notations and put the problem into a general form, let $A_N\equiv A\in\mathcal{M}_{2N+1}(\mathbb{C})$ (so $A$ plays the role of $K_N$ above) and
\begin{align*}
A'&:=\begin{pmatrix}E_1&E_2&E_3\\E_4&A&E_5\\E_6&E_7&E_8\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{M}_{2N'+1}(\mathbb{C})
\end{align*}
where $E_1,E_3,E_6,E_8\in\mathcal{M}_{N'-N}(\mathbb{C})$, $E_2,E_7\in\mathcal{M}_{N'-N,2N+1}(\mathbb{C})$ and $E_4,E_5\in\mathcal{M}_{2N+1,N'-N}(\mathbb{C})$ have $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norms $\leq\varepsilon$; we also have that $\sum_{k}|E_j|_{kk}\leq\varepsilon$ by the trace-class property of $K$. Typically, the coefficients of $A'$ decay as "we move to the exterior" of $A$', that is:
\begin{align*}
&|(E_2)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N'+j)^2};&&|(E_7)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N+j)^2};\\
&|(E_4)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N'+k)^2};&&|(E_5)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N+k)^2};\\
&|(E_1)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N'+j)^2},\frac{1}{(N'+k)^2};&&|(E_6)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N'+k)^2},\frac{1}{(N+j)^2};\\
&|(E_3)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N'+j)^2},\frac{1}{(N+k)^2};&&|(E_8)_{j,k}|\lesssim\frac{1}{(N+k)^2},\frac{1}{(N+j)^2}.
\end{align*}
Using the formula
\begin{align*}
\lambda\mathrm{1}_{2N+1}&=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\oint(A-\mu)^{-1}\mu\mathrm{d}\mu
\end{align*}
for all eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, we know that there exists $\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Spec}(A')\setminus\overline{D(0,1/4)}\subset\mathrm{Spec}(A)\setminus\overline{D(0,1/4)}+D(0,\delta(\varepsilon))\tag{$\star$}
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{Spec}$ denotes the spectrum of the corresponding matrix; here we removed the closed discs $\setminus\overline{D(0,1/4)}$ as we do not interest ourselves in the spectrum that accumulate at 0 (by compactness of $K$). I would like to get an explicit estimate of $\delta(\varepsilon)$. **The matrix $A$ is not normal**.

---

One way I see to prove the statement for the largest (in modulus) eigenvalues is to use the definition of the spectral radius as $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|A^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}$; but this implies to compute the coefficients of $A^n$: we can see that we obtain a matrix whose each line consists in a sum of $3^n$ products of the matrices $E_j$ and $A$, and indeed the term $A^n$ is obtained on the line $k$ for $N'+1\leq k\leq N'+2N+1$. I do not see a clean way to proceed then as terms containing $A^\ell$ with $\ell\leq n-1$ do not vanish at the limit $n\to+\infty$ (and could blow in norm as $n\to+\infty$).

Another thing I tried without success is the following: let $u\in\mathbb{C}^{2N+1}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $Au=\lambda u$ with $|\lambda|>1/4$. We look for $u'\in\mathbb{C}^{2N'+1}$ and $\lambda'\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $A'u'=\lambda'u'$ of the form
\begin{align*}
u'&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\varepsilon^ku_k,\qquad\qquad\lambda'=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\varepsilon^k\lambda_k
\end{align*}
where $u_0=(0,u,0)$ and $\lambda_0=\lambda$. The idea was then to eliminate terms of order $\varepsilon^k$ with an appropriate choice of $u_k$ and $\lambda_k$ -- perhaps by setting $\varepsilon^{2k}\lambda_k$ in the series defining $\lambda'$ instead of $\varepsilon^k\lambda_k$. I could not manage to do it so far.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, wonderful, we have now an interesting question in functional analysis on Hilbert spaces! I will take a closer look to the situation. If i correctly understand the setting, it is an *assumption* on $T$ that $T=1+K$ with a trace class operator $K$. Is it so? Also, just as a comment on shapes of the objects, that may lead to an easier work for the typist, after applying a permutation matrix mapping the indices from $-N'$ to $N'$, ordered as usual in $\Bbb Z$ to the new order $0,1,-1,2,-2,\dots, N',-N'$, i think we can rewrite $A'$ in a simpler $2\times 2$ block matrix form.

Comment: @dan_fulea Most welcome! Indeed, $T=\mathrm{1}+K$ with $K$ of trace-class is an assumption. Besides, it is perhaps easier to modify the shpes of matrices as you suggest, as long as we have an explicit control on the norm of the transformations (ok if they are unitary).

Answer (score 1):

A not-completed answer.

We denote by $\,\!^TM$ the transpose of a matrix $M$ and $\mathrm{Com}(M)$ its comatrix. Let $\mu\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, $\lambda\in C(\mu,\delta)$ and $E:=A'-A$ (embedding $A$ in $\mathcal{M}_{2N'+1}(\mathbb{C})$ by adding zero entries; note that $E_{jk}=0$ for $-N\leq j,k\leq N$). Then:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{I}:=\left|\det(A-\lambda)-\det(A'-\lambda)\right|&=\left|\int_0^1\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\big[\!\,^T\mathrm{Com}\big((A-\lambda)+t(A'-A)\big)\big]\circ(A'-A)\Big\}\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
&=\left|\int_0^1\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\big[\!\,^T\mathrm{Com}\big((A-\lambda)+tE\big)\big]\circ E\Big\}\mathrm{d}t\right|,
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{II}:=\left|\det(A-\lambda)\right|&=\left|\det\big((A-\mu)-(\lambda-\mu)\big)\right|\\
&=\left|\int_0^1\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\big[\!\,^T\mathrm{Com}\big((A-\mu)+t(\lambda-\mu)\big)\big]\circ(\lambda-\mu)\mathrm{1}_{2N'+1}\Big\}\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
&=\delta\left|\int_0^1\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\big[\!\,^T\mathrm{Com}\big((A-\mu)+t(\lambda-\mu)\big)\big]\Big\}\mathrm{d}t\right|.
\end{align*}
The trace in the last line above is the one defined on $\mathcal{M}_{2N+1}(\mathbb{C})$ since $\!\,^T\mathrm{Com}\big(A-\mu\big)\in\mathcal{M}_{2N+1}(\mathbb{C})$. Now, very roughly speaking, the first term is $\varepsilon\left|\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\big[\!\,^T\mathrm{Com}\big(A-\mu\big)\big]\Big\}\right|$ (where $\varepsilon\geq\|E\|$) while the second term is $\delta\left|\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\big[\!\,^T\mathrm{Com}\big(A-\mu\big)\big]\Big\}\right|$. So if $\varepsilon\lesssim\delta$ then Rouché's theorem asserts that there are as many zeros of $\det(A'-\lambda)$ counted with multiplicity in $C(\mu,\delta)$ as $\det(A-\lambda)$, yielding the property $(\star)$ of the original post. **It remains to rigorously prove that $\mathrm{I}<\mathrm{II}$**. I expect that we will have to use $|\lambda|,|\mu|\leq\mathrm{spectral\ radius\ of\ }(K)+\delta$.

As we let $N'\to\infty$, we do know by the trace-class property of the original operator $K$ that small eigenvalues (say in $D(0,1/4)$) will remain in $\overline{D(0,3/4)}$ if we take $N$ large enough so that $|\mathrm{Tr}(K_N)-\mathrm{Tr}(K)|\leq1/2$ (which is something we can compute explicitly).

---

**ADDENDUM:** We denote by $\widetilde{M}_{ij}$ the matrix $M$ with the $i$-th row and $j$-th column removed. We compute:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Com}(A+tH)&=\Big((-1)^{i+j}\det\big((\widetilde{A+tH})_{ij}\big)\Big)_{ij}\\
%
&=\Big((-1)^{i+j}\Big[\det\big(\widetilde{A}_{ij}\big)+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^{T}\mathrm{Com}\big((\widetilde{A+stH})_{ij}\big)\circ\widetilde{tH}_{ij}\Big\}\mathrm{d}s\Big]\Big)_{ij}\\
%
&=\mathrm{Com}(A)+\Big((-1)^{i+j}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^{T}\mathrm{Com}\big((\widetilde{A+stH})_{ij}\big)\circ\widetilde{tH}_{ij}\Big\}\mathrm{d}s\Big)_{ij}.
\end{align*}
Hence:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{I}&=\left|\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\mathrm{Com}(A-\lambda)\circ E\Big\}\mathrm{d}t\right.\\
&\quad\left.+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\Big((-1)^{i+j}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^{T}\mathrm{Com}\big((\widetilde{A-\lambda+stE})_{ij}\big)\circ\widetilde{tE}_{ij}\Big\}\Big)_{ij}\circ tE\Big\}\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t\right|,\\
%
\mathrm{II}&=\left|\delta\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\mathrm{Com}(A-\lambda)\Big\}\mathrm{d}t\right.\\
&\quad\left.+\delta\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\Big((-1)^{i+j}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^{T}\mathrm{Com}\big((\widetilde{A-\lambda+s(1+t)(\lambda-\mu)})_{ij}\big)\circ\widetilde{t(\lambda-\mu)}_{ij}\Big\}\Big)_{ij}\circ t(\lambda-\mu)\Big\}\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t\right|
\end{align*}
Now observe that $\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\mathrm{Com}(A-\lambda)\circ E\Big\}=0$ due to the zero coefficients of $\,\!^T\mathrm{Com}(A-\lambda)$. The problem is thus solved if can estimate the minimal size of $\|E\|$ satisfying:
\begin{align*}
&\left|\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\Big((-1)^{i+j}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^{T}\mathrm{Com}\big((\widetilde{A-\lambda+stE})_{ij}\big)\circ\widetilde{tE}_{ij}\Big\}\Big)_{ij}\circ tE\Big\}\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
&\quad+\delta\left|\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\Big((-1)^{i+j}\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^{T}\mathrm{Com}\big((\widetilde{A-\lambda+s(1+t)(\lambda-\mu)})_{ij}\big)\circ\widetilde{t(\lambda-\mu)}_{ij}\Big\}\Big)_{ij}\circ t(\lambda-\mu)\Big\}\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t\right|<\delta\left|\mathrm{Tr}\Big\{\,\!^T\mathrm{Com}(A-\lambda)\Big\}\right|.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The question is for me, as it stays now, not completely clear regarding the fixed $N$ from the first line, the undefined $\varepsilon$ that appears in the second line (soon used for some condition on the $E$-matrices), then the fact that in the next line $N$ (fixed) and $\varepsilon$ become variables for the estimation, and are related to each other. These lines were first written as a comment, but did not fit in the very restricted comment box, so they became an answer. I will let this unclear fact about $N$ and $\varepsilon$ as it is, and just start a particular example to illustrate my problems with the framework.

---

There is no specification about the shapes of the block matrices involved in $A$, so i will assume (as a particular case of the given very general situation) that the block matrices on the diagonal of $A'$ have square shape, i am conjugating with a permutation matrix, so the problem deals with the eigenvalues of the matrices $B$ (permutation conjugation of $A'$) and those of $A$, where $A,B$ are related by
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
A & E_{12}\\
E_{21} & E_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
Of course, we can now consider in full generality characteristic polynomials and try to say something about coefficients. But let us work in a simple toy example where $A$ is a diagonal matrix with (e.g. distinct, e.g. real, and best spaced with at least $2\varepsilon$ distance between them) eigenvalues $a_1<a_2<a_3<\dots$ which are "big" (e.g. around one or around $1000$), and where $E_{22}$ is diagonal with (e.g. distinct, e.g. real) "small" (i.e. bounded by $\varepsilon$) eigenvalues $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\dots$
and let us finally let the non-diagonal $E$-blocks vanish. Then $B$ (and $A'$) has the spectrum $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}\cup\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\dots\}$ which is not located inside an $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of Spec$(A)=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$.

For my understanding, the set Spec$(A)+D(0,\delta(\varepsilon)$ is in the case of spaced $A$-eigenvalues the set
$$
\bigcup_j D(a_j, \delta(\varepsilon))\ ,
$$
and the spectrum of $B$ is not contained in the above set for a "small" $\delta(\varepsilon)$. (Since it contains also some "small" eigenvalues $
 \varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\dots$ which are far away from the $A$-eigenvalues.)

---

Please give some more details about the situation where the estimation should be applied. Or please show what should work in the case of a block-diagonal $A'$ with a fixed (even diagonal $A$) and diagonal remaining blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I did add more details and background in my original post, I do hope it will help. You were right: it may happen that the spectrum of the big matrix $A'$ be not at small distance to the spectrum of the small matrix $A$, but in that case, the corresponding spectrum lies in a small disc centered at 0 and we do not care about it. I made it clear in my edited post.